# Elegant way to move an initializer behind the conditional in for loop

Tags: c++

I have a loop over a random access iterator.  Typical usage is that end() is past-the-end, and should not be dereferenced, so I need to perform my conditional BEFORE I start initializing stuff.  Here's my specific code:

```
template <typename RAI>
void foo(RAI begin, RAI end) {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RAI>::value_type VT;

  SOME_TYPE<VT> key = SOME_TYPE<VT>(*begin);

  while (begin != end) {
    do_stuff(key);
    do_more_stuff(key);
    key = SOME_TYPE<VT>(*++begin)
  }
}
```

If begin==end when the function is called, then I end up dereferencing end, which is in memory space that I may not own.  I can't declare `SOME_TYPE<VT> key;` if either `SOME_TYPE` or `VT` don't have empty constructors.  I could put an `if...then` at the beginning, but that seems so.... ugly.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not just do this?

```
template <typename RAI>
void foo(RAI begin, RAI end) {
  typedef typename std::iterator_traits<RAI>::value_type VT;

  for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
    SOME_TYPE<VT> key = SOME_TYPE<VT>(*begin);
    do_stuff(key);
    do_more_stuff(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will it complain of multiple declarations?

Comment: It gripes about declaring it before the loop, if there aren't empty constructors for the relevant types.

Comment: Huh.  Somehow I was under the impression that I couldn't declare a variable in my loop.... TIL

Comment: @Scott declaring inside the loop is fine.